# FCM Push Notif script

Tags: php, android

I followed a tutorial to do Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notifications using the Android Studio.
Here's the tuto : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYZVhs6T_W8
So i got a problem with my push_notification.php :

```
<?php 
    function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'data' => $message
            );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key = AAAALXOnumg:APA91bGI7Qfrl0XVX52KOfjfKfzFcezbD6mwwIti7oswMAvGn3Z9Q1toxJ9IiXiXRFc_vB21NRnwNaI-vYPxcEMO5JH53RrfAtnjxyA5fzaiwONSnLY987ephLapy0ijTyW9VLwwoPBJSq',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
    }

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","toor","gcm");
    $sql = " Select Token From users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $tokens = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    $message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
    $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
    echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

And there's the result when i execute it on my browser :  [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]

My DB id's are correct, the Auth Key too, so where the problem come from ?

Comment: check with this link to confirm you are getting push by giving your fcm token https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: So in setting, there's server key and a Legacy server key, i tried both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","toor","gcm");
```

Please check these details it should be (host, dbname, username, password).